# the show more button is not in the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple website for my college project, the problem is that the "show more" button is overlapped by the image slide-show I made.

Here's my code snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.classList.add("active");
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const content = document.querySelector(".content");
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (isInViewport(content) && !content.classList.contains("active")) {
      content.classList.add("active");
    }
  });

  function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }



});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  let currentSlide = 0;
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-image');

  function changeSlide(index) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
    currentSlide = index;
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
  }

  function autoSlide() {
    changeSlide((currentSlide + 1) % slides.length);
  }

  setInterval(autoSlide, 3000);

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.align {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 14px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.video-wrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.4s linear;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 1.6, 0.4, 0.7);
}

.btn1::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.btn1:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.btn-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
}

.container.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 80%;
}

.text-box {
  background-color: rgba(0, 92, 230, 0.5);
  padding: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.centered-text {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slider-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-image {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 2px solid rgb(111, 111, 220);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(153, 153, 230, 0.3);
  z-index: 0;
}

.slider-image.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.button-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: both;
}

.txt {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profile.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/indexstyle.css">
  <script src="js scripts/sript.js"></script>
  <script src="js scripts/slideshow.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: white;">
  <div class="container">
    <header style="background-color: white;">
      <h1 class="align">
        Shiroe
      </h1>
      <h3>
        <nav class="topnav">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="artworks.html">Art Works</a>
          <a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
        </nav>
      </h3>
    </header>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="media\mainmenuheader.jpeg" alt="character" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <div class="text-box">
          <h1 class="centered-text" style="font-size: xx-large; margin-bottom: 20px;">Welcome</h1>
          <h1 class="centered-text" style="font-size: xxx-large; margin-bottom: 20px">MY Personal Blog</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="txt">My Art Works</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-container">
      <div class="slider-image-container">
        <img src="media\ArtWorks\5.jpg" alt="img2" class="slider-image active">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-image-container">
        <img src="media\ArtWorks\Artheist4.jpg" alt="img3" class="slider-image">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-image-container">
        <img src="media\ArtWorks\bday_illust_fine.jpg" alt="img4" class="slider-image">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-image-container">
        <img src="media\ArtWorks\praktise2.jpg" alt="img5" class="slider-image">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <a href="artworks.html" class="btn btn1">Show More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope to know what is the problem and how to solve it for me to be aware in the future. I just started learning HTML,CSS, and JS. Thank You.

Comment: Please take the time to minimise the amount of code you're sharing (see: "*[mcve]*"), the overlapping elements are likely caused by CSS, rather than JavaScript so - rather than pasting everything into your example, remove the JavaScript and insert static (non-dynamic) content into the HTML to reproduce the issue. Extra code tends to obfuscate the problem(s) you're trying to get help with, rather than helping. I imagine you'll track the problem down to the use of `float` and `position: absolute`, both of which take elements out of the normal flow.